# How to convert a sql object into a multidimensional array?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I wrote this simple code and I extracted two columns from MySQL table. Then I couldnt convert it into a multidimensional array.

So the table I had,have only 2 rows and what I expected it will give me a output of 2 rows and 2 columns. But instead the array size came out to be 4(instead of 2) and moreover its giving an error for the printing of `temp[2]` and `temp[3]`

```
<?php 
mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); //Connecting to the localhost
mysql_select_db("user"); //Selecting a database
$auth_data = mysql_query("SELECT EMAIL,UNIQUE_ID FROM authentication"); 
#Converting the object to an array
$temp = mysql_fetch_array($auth_data, MYSQL_BOTH);
echo sizeOf($temp);
echo $temp[0];
echo $temp[1];
echo $temp[2];
echo $temp[3];
?>
```

Error:

```
4abhinav.chawla@iiitb.org1

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test.php on line 12
```

Comment: `mysql_fetch_array()` only fetches one row (its columns as an array); it then advances the pointer so that the next call will fetch the next row.  You need to call it repeatedly, usually in a loop like `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($auth_data)) do_something_with($row);`.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `MYSQL_BOTH`, so you get both numeric and string keys into `$temp`, which holds just *the first* result of your query.

Use `PDO/mysqli` and drop `mysql_*` please.

Answer (score 0):

```
 you selected only two fields  so output will be two parameter.

> select emailadn uniqueid from tablename. parameter $temp[0]; $temp [1]
> ..................... $temp[2] $temp[3] wrong array
```